# next-auth middleware causing api-routes-static-export warning

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to use next-auth, and want certain portions of the site protected in different ways. I believe I'm properly following the [example in the next-auth docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#advanced-usage),
but at build time, I'm getting a warning:

> warn  - Statically exporting a Next.js application via `next export` disables API routes and middleware.
> This command is meant for static-only hosts, and is not necessary to make your application static.
> Pages in your application without server-side data dependencies will be automatically statically exported by `next build`, including pages powered by `getStaticProps`.
> Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/api-routes-static-export

If I remove the `middleware.js` file, the warning disappears, so it's definitely the issue. How do I fix this?

```
// middleware.js
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';

export default withAuth({
    callbacks: {
        authorized: ({ req, token }) => {
            // `/admin` requires admin role
            if (req.nextUrl.pathname === "/admin") {
                return token?.userRole === "admin"
            }
            // `/exclusive` requires approval
            if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/exclusive') {
                return (token?.exclusive && token.exclusive !== 'APPLIED');
            }
            
            // `/downloads` only requires the user to be logged in
            return !!token
        },
    },
})
  
export const config = { matcher: ["/admin/:path*", "/downloads/:path*", "/exclusive/:path*"] }
```